# Vertical positioning of a label in enumerate with multicolumn

Tags: vertical-alignment, lists, enumerate

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newlist{myQuoteEnumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myQuoteEnumerate,1]{label=(\arabic*),leftmargin=0cm,labelsep=-1.7em}
\newenvironment{MyQuote}{\begin{myQuoteEnumerate}[resume=*,series=MyQuoteSeries] \item
\begin{quote}}{\end{quote}
\end{myQuoteEnumerate}}
\begin{document}
\begin{MyQuote} \small \begin{tabularx}{336pt}[t]{@{}p{168pt}X@{}}
\multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{\parbox{336pt}{\Centering So when these criminal organizations in the future need someone gone, they use specialized assassins in our present called loopers.}} \\ \midrule 
\textit{Pokud tyto zločinecké} & \textit{Když tihle zločinci z budoucností} \\
\textit{organizace potřebují někoho zabít,} & \textit{chtějí někoho zlikvidovat,} \\   \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-2}
\textit{využijí specializované} & \textit{využijí zabijáky z naší} \\
\textit{nájemné vrahy v naší přítomnosti,} & \textit{přítomnosti, takzvané loopery.}\\ \cmidrule(r){1-1}
\textit{takzvané Loopery.} & 
\end{tabularx}\end{MyQuote}\normalsize
\begin{MyQuote}
\small \begin{tabularx}{336pt}[t]{@{}p{168pt}X@{}}
\multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{This is called “closing your loop”.} \\ \midrule 
\textit{Říká se tomu} & Tím se smyčka uzavře, \\   
\textit{"uzavřít svého loopa."} & zabalíme loopa. 
\end{tabularx}
\end{MyQuote}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, (1) is aligned with the middle of the first two rows, unlike (2), which is aligned with the middle of the first row. Can I make it so that the label would always be aligned with the top of the item in enumerate?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to add `t` (top alignment) for the `\parbox`:

[image]

The code (I also used the `>{...}` syntax to simplify a little the code, but this is optional):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newlist{myQuoteEnumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myQuoteEnumerate,1]{label=(\arabic*),leftmargin=0cm,labelsep=-1.7em}
\newenvironment{MyQuote}{\begin{myQuoteEnumerate}[resume=*,series=MyQuoteSeries] \item
\begin{quote}}{\end{quote}
\end{myQuoteEnumerate}}
\begin{document}
\begin{MyQuote} \small \begin{tabularx}{336pt}[t]{@{}>{\itshape}p{168pt}>{\itshape}X@{}}
\multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{\parbox[t]{336pt}{\Centering So when these criminal organizations in the future need someone gone, they use specialized assassins in our present called loopers.}} \\ \midrule 
Pokud tyto zločinecké & Když tihle zločinci z budoucností \\
organizace potřebují někoho zabít, & chtějí někoho zlikvidovat, \\   \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-2}
využijí specializované & využijí zabijáky z naší \\
nájemné vrahy v naší přítomnosti, & přítomnosti, takzvané loopery.\\ \cmidrule(r){1-1}
takzvané Loopery. & 
\end{tabularx}\end{MyQuote}\normalsize
\begin{MyQuote}
\small \begin{tabularx}{336pt}[t]{@{}>{\itshape}p{168pt}>{\itshape}X@{}}
\multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{This is called “closing your loop”.} \\ \midrule 
Říká se tomu & Tím se smyčka uzavře, \\   
"uzavřít svého loopa." & zabalíme loopa. 
\end{tabularx}
\end{MyQuote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but misplaced the parameter actually:-).